# How to write this javascript code in correct way?

Tags: javascript

```
var dril1 = (count1[0]*m[1])+(count1[1]*m[2])+(count1[2]*m[3])+(count1[3]*m[4])+(count1[4]*m[5])+(count1[5]*m[6]);
var dril2 = (count2[0]*m[1])+(count2[1]*m[2])+(count2[2]*m[3])+(count2[3]*m[4])+(count2[4]*m[5])+(count2[5]*m[6]);
var dril3 = (count3[0]*m[1])+(count3[1]*m[2])+(count3[2]*m[3])+(count3[3]*m[4])+(count3[4]*m[5])+(count3[5]*m[6]);
var dril4 = (count4[0]*m[1])+(count4[1]*m[2])+(count4[2]*m[3])+(count4[3]*m[4])+(count4[4]*m[5])+(count4[5]*m[6]);
var dril5 = (count5[0]*m[1])+(count5[1]*m[2])+(count5[2]*m[3])+(count5[3]*m[4])+(count5[4]*m[5])+(count5[5]*m[6]);
var dril6 = (count6[0]*m[1])+(count6[1]*m[2])+(count6[2]*m[3])+(count6[3]*m[4])+(count6[4]*m[5])+(count6[5]*m[6]);
```

Is there other possible way to write this piece of code ?

Comment: If those count-variables were in an array, then yes...

Comment: "Is there other possible way to write this piece of code ?" Yes there is. I like when it is a yes/no type of question.

Comment: Btw, you don't need parens - multiplication comes before addition.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
var counts = [ count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6 ];
```

And then:

```
var drils = counts.map(function ( count ) {
    return count.reduce(function ( prev, curr, i ) {
        return prev + curr * m[ i + 1 ];
    }, 0 );
});
```

The `.map()` Array method will return a new array of results based on the `counts` array. The `.reduce()` Array method will reduce each `count` element into a single value.

Comment: +1 for the .map() function. Could you explain a bit of your code? What do reduce() and map() do exactly?

Comment: @PaoloStefan I recommend MDN: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing it this way? Other than feeling like a boss and confusing 95% of people who look at your code? ;)

Comment: @rrowland Well, believe it or not `:P`, the Array iteration methods have been introduced to the language for a reason. Compared to for-loops (which they replace), they are more high-level, more expressive (the intent of the code is easier recognizable), and they also create a new scope (which is desirable, if local variables have to be used within the iteration). I **recommend** that you read them up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods).

Answer (score 0):

`count[1...6]` and `drill[1...6]` should actually be its own array. You could then loop through the elements and make the calls that way.

```
var drill = []
for(var i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    drill.push((count[i][0]*m[1]/* rest of the statement */));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could maybe use a 2D array and then use a double for loop?

Answer (score 0):

At the least, you can do the sums in a loop:

```
var dril1 = 0, dril2 = 2, ...;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    dril1 += count1[i] * m[i + 1];
    dril2 += count2[i] * m[i + 1];
    . . .
}
```

It could be compacted much further if `dril1`, ..., `dril6` and `count1`, ..., `count6` were two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor out the calculation:

```
function calc(count) {
  return count[0] * m[1] + count[1] * m[2] + count[2] * m[3] + count[3] * m[4] + count[4] * m[5] + count[5] * m[6];
}

var dril1 = calc(count1);
var dril2 = calc(count2);
var dril3 = calc(count3);
var dril4 = calc(count4);
var dril5 = calc(count5);
var dril6 = calc(count6);
```

Comment: Don't you mean to be using `count` inside `calc` instead of `count1`?

Comment: @TedHopp: Yes. I already fixed that. :)

Answer (score 0):

For each dril you could do:

var dril1 = (count1[0]*m[1])+(count1[1]*m[2])+(count1[2]*m[3])+(count1[3]*m[4])+(count1[4]*m[5])+(count1[5]*m[6]);

```
var dril1 = 0;
var dril2 = 0;
for (var i=0, len=count1.length; i<len; i++) {
  dril1 += (count1[i]*m[i+1]);
  dril2 += (count2[i]*m[i+1]);
}
```

but if you had each count as a member of an array:

```
var dril = [];
for (var i=0, lenI=count.length; i<lenI; i++) {
  dril[i] = 0;
  for (var j=0, lenJ=count[i].length; j<lenJ; j++) {
    dril[i] += (count[i][j]*m[j+1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: else if(plastic>0){
        var count1=["101","101","101","101","101","101"];
        var count2=["101","101","101","101","101","101"];
        var count3=["101","101","101","101","101","101"];
        var count4=["101","101","101","101","101","101"];
        var count5=["101","101","101","101","101","101"];
        var count6=["2.17","9","12.5","25","33.33","50"];